# event listener to close current dialog

Tags: javascript, dialog

The below code only works for the first dialog (BOB JONES) and the second dialog (ROBERT ABREAU) will open but not close onclick outside the dialog. I will have 150 more dialogs of text associated with student photos of a chess grandmaster. So IDK if I can use an event listener as per closeDialog() to close the current open dialog. Maybe a solution would involve **getElementsByClassName**. And I could patch that into the js code below, and omit the "onclick = "closeDialog();" on each dialog.

**What's a good plan?**

## html

```
<!-- BOB JONES -->
<dialog id = "B-JONES" onclick = "closeDialog('B-JONES');">
<div class="test">
<p>Blah blah blah</p>
</div>
</dialog>
<!-- END BOB JONES

<!-- ROBERT ABREAU -->
<dialog id = "R-ABREAU" onclick = "closeDialog('R-ABREAU');">
<div class="test">
<p>Blah blah blah</p>
</div>
</dialog>
<!-- END ROBERT ABREAU -->
```

... 150 more

## JS

```
function closeDialog(dialogID) {
 document.querySelector('dialog').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
if(!e.target.closest('div')) { e.target.close();}
 });
}
```

Comment: Why not have a general function that closes dialogs and you pass in the dialog's ID to it? That way it will be triggered on a specific dialog.

Comment: Why, yes! That's exactly what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your comment, the code you are looking for can be somewhere along these lines:

```
<!-- BOB JONES -->
<dialog id = "B-JONES" onclick = "closeDialog('B-JONES');">
<div class="test">
<p>Blah blah blah</p>
</div>
</dialog>
<!-- END BOB JONES

<!-- ROBERT ABREAU -->
<dialog id = "R-ABREAU" onclick = "closeDialog('R-ABREAU');">
<div class="test">
<p>Blah blah blah</p>
</div>
</dialog>
<!-- END ROBERT ABREAU -->
```

**JS**

```
 function closeDialog(dialogID) {
 let dialog = document.getElementById(dialogId);
 if (dialog) {
      dialog.close();
 }
}
```

Just make sure that the IDs of your dialogs are unique.